# Coerce to multiple-parameter type in Haskell

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, coercion

I have a type

```
class IntegerAsType a where
  value :: a -> Integer

data T5
instance IntegerAsType T5 where value _ = 5

newtype (Num a, IntegerAsType n) => PolyRing a n = PolyRing [a]
```

My main question is: how do I define a variable in a particular `PolyRing`?

It should be something like:

```
x = [1, 2, 3] :: Integer T5
```

(I think)
The question is: what is the correct syntax after the `::`?

I'm getting the error

```
Couldn't match expected type `PolyRing Integer T5'
         with actual type `[t0]'
In the expression: [1, 2, 3] :: PolyRing Integer T5
In an equation for `x': x = [1, 2, 3] :: PolyRing Integer T5
```

Also, I'm looking for a better way to implement this. In particular, I'd really like for the type `a` to be inferred from the type of list elements, while the `IntegerAsType n` must be specified (it shouldn't depend on the length of the list, even if that is possible).

Things I've tried so far:

```
x = [1,2,3] :: PolyRing (Integer, T5)

x = [1,2,3] :: PolyRing Integer T5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Note**

Data type contexts, such as:

```
newtype (Num a, IntegerAsType n) => PolyRing a n = PolyRing [a]
```

are generally a bad idea and have been retired from the language.

**Ignoring That**

To construct an instance you must use the data constructor `PolyRing`:

```
PolyRing [1,2,3]
```

But that isn't enough, the type inference so far will be `(IntegerAsType n) => PolyRing Integer n`.  Your final type signature would finish this up `let x = PolyRing [1,2,3] :: PolyRing Integer T5`.

**Returning To the First Note**

Still, perhaps you wanted:

```
newtype PolyRing a n = PolyRing [a]
```

And every function that builds or consumes a polyring can enforce the needed constraints:

```
func :: (Num a, IntegerAsType n) => PolyRing a n -> ...
```

Answer (score 2):

A `newtype` is not just a synonym but a way to create a type that is distinct at the type level (though identical later). That said - you need to wrap it explicitly using your data constructor. Also, the context has no effect. You still have to type it everywhere.